# ciclo for no recorre correctamente, reemplaza a todos por el ultimo dato, los cuales estan almacenados en una base de datos

Tags: android, json

Hola Buen día estoy realizando mi primera app y lo que sucede es que la información que se tendrá en la aplicación, sera extraída desde una base de datos y si tengo conexión con ella.

Tengo un ciclo `for` con el que llamo a varios estados para que aparezcan en pantalla y solo me muestra el ultimo dato, osea no lo esta recorriendo correctamente, reemplaza a los demás por este ultimo.

Aquí les dejo el código, su apoyo me serviría de gran ayuda.

Gracias.

```
  @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            rutaList = new ArrayList<>();
            conexionJson jOj = new conexionJson();
            Turismo map = new Turismo();

            try { JSONObject jsonObject = jOj.getJSONObjectFromURL("http://guanajuato.gob.mx/WSAppGto/enlace.php?metodo=pa_get_all_turismo");

                JSONArray jsonA = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Resultado");
                {
                        int id;
                        String nombre;
                        String descripcion;
                        Double latitud;
                        Double longitud;
                        String tipo;
                        String imagen;
                        int i = 0;

                    for ( i = 0; i < jsonA.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject row = jsonA.getJSONObject(i);


                        id = row.getInt("idturismo");
                        nombre = row.getString("nombre");
                        descripcion = row.getString("descripcion");
                        latitud = row.getDouble("latitud");
                        longitud = row.getDouble("latitud");
                        tipo = row.getString("tipo");
                        imagen = row.getString("imagen");
                        switch (imagen) {
                            case "Dolores Hidalgo":
                                title = "http:\\/\\/doloreshidalgo.gob.mx\\/images\\/dolores-hidalgo-cin.png";
                                break;
                            case "Yurira":
                                title = "descarga.jpg";
                                break;
                        }


                        System.out.println(i);
                        System.out.println(nombre);



                        map.setId("1");
                        map.setNombre((String) nombre);
                        map.setDescripcion((String) descripcion);
                        map.setLatitud((Double) 0.0);
                        map.setLongitud((Double) 0.0);
                        map.setTipo((String) tipo);
                        map.setIdNombre("");
                        map.setImagen((String) imagen);
                        map.setDetalles("");
                        map.setImg(1);
                        rutaList.add(map);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
```

Y en consola si me da los 3 nombres que tengo en la base de datos 
I/System.out: JSON:

```
>   {"Resultado":[{"idturismo":1,nombre:"Dolores
> Hidalgo"},{"idturismo":2,"nombre":"yuriria",{"idturismo":3,"nombre":"San
> Miguel de Allende"
>     I/System.out: 0
>     I/System.out: Dolores Hidalgo
>     I/System.out: 1
>     I/System.out: yuriria
>     I/System.out: 2
>     I/System.out: San Miguel de Allende
```

Comment: intenta, instanciar el objeto "map" en cada iteraccion del for
**ejemplo:**
  `for ( i = 0; i < jsonA.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject row = jsonA.getJSONObject(i);
     map = new MiClase();
     ..... mas codigo
     ....... aun mas
}`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
    rutaList = new ArrayList<>();
    conexionJson jOj = new conexionJson();
    Turismo map = new Turismo();

    try { JSONObject jsonObject = jOj.getJSONObjectFromURL("http://guanajuato.gob.mx/WSAppGto/enlace.php?metodo=pa_get_all_turismo");

        JSONArray jsonA = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Resultado");
        {
                int id;
                String nombre;
                String descripcion;
                Double latitud;
                Double longitud;
                String tipo;
                String imagen;
                int i = 0;

            for ( i = 0; i < jsonA.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = jsonA.getJSONObject(i);


                id = row.getInt("idturismo");
                nombre = row.getString("nombre");
                descripcion = row.getString("descripcion");
                latitud = row.getDouble("latitud");
                longitud = row.getDouble("latitud");
                tipo = row.getString("tipo");
                imagen = row.getString("imagen");
                switch (imagen) {
                    case "Dolores Hidalgo":
                        title = "http:\\/\\/doloreshidalgo.gob.mx\\/images\\/dolores-hidalgo-cin.png";
                        break;
                    case "Yurira":
                        title = "descarga.jpg";
                        break;
                }


                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(nombre);



                map.setId("1");
                map.setNombre((String) nombre);
                map.setDescripcion((String) descripcion);
                map.setLatitud((Double) 0.0);
                map.setLongitud((Double) 0.0);
                map.setTipo((String) tipo);
                map.setIdNombre("");
                map.setImagen((String) imagen);
                map.setDetalles("");
                map.setImg(1);
                //setea la posición del elemento a agregar
                rutaList.add(i, map);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo resultado, a caso estoy fallamdo en como realizar el ciclo for o el json??

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que el problema es que esta añadiendo a `rutaList` la misma instancia x veces, usted la modifica en cada iteracion, con el uso de setters ect, pero la instancia es la misma, no lo nota al principio, o tampoco lo notaria aunque hiciera `System.out.println(map.setNombre());` dentro del `for` pues le mostraria el ultimo valor que tiene esa instancia para ese campo, en este caso para el nombre.

Ahora eso se ve reflejado cuando recorre el `ArrayList` en algun punto, pues aunque la capacidad del `ArrayList` sea de 3, todas son de la misma instancia.

Un ejemplo espero le ayude:

Este creo funciona de similar manera a lo que usted comenta:

<kbd>[ideone test 1](https://ideone.com/sexJHI)</kbd>

Y este funciona como creo que usted esperaria:

<kbd>[ideone test 2](https://ideone.com/CRWXSp)</kbd>

Fijese que el principal cambio es que dentro del `for` se crea una nueva instancia para `Test`, que en este caso es la simulacion de su clase Turismo, que despues se le pasa al ArrayList.

---

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here

        ArrayList<Test> rutaList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Test map = new Test();
        String[] testa = {"hola", "test", "aqui"};

        String nombre;


        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            Test map = new Test(); 

            nombre = testa[i];

            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(nombre);

            map.setNombre((String) nombre);

            rutaList.add(map);
        }


        //miramos rutaList
        System.out.println("---");

        for(int a = 0; a < rutaList.size(); a++){
            System.out.println(rutaList.get(a).getNombre());
        }
    }
}

class Test{

    String nombre;

    public void setNombre(String n){
        this.nombre = n;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
}
```

*lo he intentado explicar de una manera sencilla espero lo entendiera.*

P.D: *Tengo un ciclo for con el que llamo a varios estados para que aparezcan en pantalla y solo me muestra el ultimo dato, osea no lo esta recorriendo correctamente...* Posiblemente si lo este recorriendo correctamente, simplemente es posible que el error este en lo que se expone en la respuesta.

Comment: Hola hola muchas gracias por tu apoyo me fue de gran ayuda..!!!