# Cómo pasar un ArrayList de un objeto de Java al main?

Tags: java

Buenos días,

soy un recién llegado tanto a Stack Overflow como al mundo de la programación en Java, apenas llevo un par de semanas.

Estoy desarrollando un programa de cartas que genera un vector con los primeros 40 números (del 1 al 40 y sin repetirse) de manera aleatoria con `Math.Random`.

El objetivo final es que genere del 1 al 10 de cada uno de los 4 palos existentes en una baraja.

A base de meter `SystemOut`s por casi todo el código he ido avanzando y el programa genera correctamente los números, los guarda, los divide y les asigna los 4 palos, pero a la hora de mostrarlos muestra los 40 valores del `ArrayList` idénticos (por ej:"6 de oros").

Entiendo que es un error de bulto pero llevo un par de mañanas y no doy con él.

Os dejo el código de la clase que genera todo y el poco que tengo en el `main` (que creo es donde está el problema):

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Baraja {
    ArrayList<Carta> naipes=new ArrayList<>();
    public Baraja() {
        int vectornum[]=new int[40];
        vectornum[0]=(int)(Math.random()*40)+1;
        Carta objeto=new Carta();
        for (int i=1;i<40;i++) {
            int tempnum=(int)(Math.random()*40)+1;
            boolean hayigual=false;
            for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if (tempnum==vectornum[j]) hayigual=true;
            }
            if (hayigual==false) 
                vectornum[i]=tempnum;
            else i--;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<40;i++) {
            if (vectornum[i]<=10) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]);
                objeto.setPalo("de Oros");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
            if (vectornum[i]>10 && vectornum[i]<=20) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]-10);
                objeto.setPalo("de Bastos");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
            if (vectornum[i]>20 && vectornum[i]<=30) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]-20);
                objeto.setPalo("de Copas");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
            if (vectornum[i]>30 && vectornum[i]<=40) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]-30);
                objeto.setPalo("de Espadas");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
        }
    }
    public void mostrarcartas () {
        for (int i=0;i<naipes.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
        }
    }
}
```

Y el main:

```
public class Mus {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baraja objeto2=new Baraja();
        objeto2.mostrarcartas();
    }
}
```

Lo que me devuelve es lo siguiente:

```
1 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
5 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
2 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
7 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
7 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
3 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
3 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
9 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
1 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
1 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
9 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
8 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
4 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
10 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
6 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
10 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
9 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
10 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
5 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
8 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
8 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
2 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
4 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
5 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
9 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
6 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
1 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
7 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
7 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
2 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
2 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
3 VALOR OBJETO de Oros
5 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
8 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
4 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
4 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
6 VALOR OBJETO de Bastos
3 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
6 VALOR OBJETO de Espadas
10 VALOR OBJETO de Copas
// Hasta aquí son los SystemOut que tengo metidos todavía para comprobar 
que generaba todo ok. Lo que devuelve el programa al final es:

10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
10 de Copas
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso a simple vista que su problema es similar al de esta pregunta:

[ciclo for no recorre correctamente, reemplaza a todos por el ultimo dato, los cuales estan almacenados en una base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53034/ciclo-for-no-recorre-correctamente-reemplaza-a-todos-por-el-ultimo-dato-los-cu/53135#53135)

usted tiene que crear una nueva instancia `Carta` dentro del segundo for algo asi:

`//.. for (int i=0;i<40;i++) {   Carta objeto=new Carta();...//`

para que en cada iteracion se cree una nueva y no use siempre el mismo, que sera al que se agregan los valores, ahora lo que usted esta haciendo es modificar la misma instancia que crea al comienzo, y por eso siempre agrega la misma y esta al final del for tiene el ultimo valor añadido de ahi a su resultado.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Baraja {
    ArrayList<Carta> naipes=new ArrayList<>();
    public Baraja() {
        int vectornum[]=new int[40];
        vectornum[0]=(int)(Math.random()*40)+1;
        //Carta objeto=new Carta();
        for (int i=1;i<40;i++) {
            int tempnum=(int)(Math.random()*40)+1;
            boolean hayigual=false;
            for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if (tempnum==vectornum[j]) hayigual=true;
            }
            if (hayigual==false) 
                vectornum[i]=tempnum;
            else i--;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<40;i++) {

         Carta objeto=new Carta();  //añadir

            if (vectornum[i]<=10) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]);
                objeto.setPalo("de Oros");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
            if (vectornum[i]>10 && vectornum[i]<=20) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]-10);
                objeto.setPalo("de Bastos");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
            if (vectornum[i]>20 && vectornum[i]<=30) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]-20);
                objeto.setPalo("de Copas");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
            if (vectornum[i]>30 && vectornum[i]<=40) {
                objeto.setNumero(vectornum[i]-30);
                objeto.setPalo("de Espadas");
                naipes.add(objeto);
                System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" VALOR OBJETO "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
            }
        }
    }
    public void mostrarcartas () {
        for (int i=0;i<naipes.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(naipes.get(i).getNumero()+" "+naipes.get(i).getPalo());
        }
    }
}
```