# Problema al agregar valores a una lista de vectores

Tags: java

lo que pasa es que necesito crear una lista de vectores, en el momento que agrego el vector a la lista utilizando  `listado.add(x);`, se agrega el ultimo valor en todos los campo de la lista, por lo tanto al terminar de agregar los valores tengo una lista con el ultimo valor de `x` en todos los campos

```
    public static List<int[]> get(int n, int inicio, int fin)
{   
     List<int[]> listado = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] x = new int[n];
    int f = 1, g, h, i, j, k, l;


    if(n == 4){
        i=inicio;
        while(i<=fin-3){
            j=i+1;
            while(j<=fin-2){
                k=j+1;
                while(k<=fin-1){
                    l=k+1;
                    while(l<=fin){
                        x[0]=i;
                        x[1]=j;
                        x[2]=k;
                        x[3]=l;
                        listado.add(x); 
                        f++;
                        l++;
                        System.out.println("["+x[0]+", "+x[1]+", "+x[2]+", "+x[3]+"]");
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= listado.size() - 1; i++) {
        String arrStr = Arrays.toString(listado.get(i));
        String hoi = arrStr.substring(1, arrStr.length()-1);
        System.out.println("lista "+i+" = "+arrStr);
  }

    return listado;
}
```

Comment: su error puede estar relacionado con esta respuesta -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58049/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-un-arraylist-de-un-objeto-de-java-al-main/58053#58053 quizas pueda poner esta linea o similar `int[] x = new int[n];` dentro del ultimo `while`. En esta otra respuesta se explica con algunos ejemplos -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53034/ciclo-for-no-recorre-correctamente-reemplaza-a-todos-por-el-ultimo-dato-los-cu/53135#53135. Saludos

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!